# WAMP and SQLSRV: sqlsrv not included in `PDO::getAvailableDrivers()` after install

Tags: pdo, wamp, wampserver, sqlsrv

I've never been able to get SQL Server to play nicely in my WAMP environment, and I trying to finally solve it once and for all.

Tried:

- Downloaded the latest SQL Server drivers from microsoft, then extracted and dropped them in my ***\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext*** dir.
- I edited both the ***\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\php.ini*** and ***\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.2\bin\php.ini*** files to include `extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll`.
- restarted all WAMP services
- checked phpinfo ... no SQLSRV
- checked `PDO::getAvailableDrivers()` ...  got only `Array( [0]=>mysql, [1]=>sqlite )`

Now, I understand that PDO is included natively in PHP 5.3+, but since the MS instructions explicitly requires that `extension=php_pdo.dll` be enabled, so I figured I'd give that a shot too.

I downloaded the DLL from dlldll.com (1st encounter with that site, so I *hoping* it's a reputable source), extracted and moved the _php_pdo.dll_ file to my ***\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.3\ext*** dir, then added it into both the php.ini files ... no improvement.

As a side note, when I check the list of activated PHP ext's from the WAMPSERVER menu, the sqlserver extensions don't even show up on the list.

Just to test it out, I also tried uncommenting `extension=php_pdo_pgsql.dll` in the *php.ini*'s, and that worked just fine ... "pgsql" *was* included in the avail drivers array.

My setup:

- Wampserver 2.2 (64bit), running

  - Apache 2.4.2
  - PHP 5.4.3
- Win 7 pro 64

What next?

I'm just about out of ideas.

The only thing I can think of is that maybe the SQLSRV drivers are 32bit, and not playing nicely with my 64bit setup ... ooohhh goodness .. I sure hope not.

***Any*** tips/pointers are welcome ... *especially* if they don't include completely reinstalling ;)

Comment: What errors are you getting when you start apache in your php error log? Is it saying the dll is not found? Your computer's bit-ness shouldn't be a problem as long as your WAMP and extensions are 32-bit you will be fine.

Comment: Wishful thinking helped me ignore that 64-bit WAMP note... I've had nothing but trouble from 64-bit WAMP - seems like the only extension I ever need (no matter what it is) is only available in 32-bit. As for the php error log - are you sure you are looking at the right one? The path will be in your php.ini file. If PHP is failing to load an extension you configure it to run, it should have an entry there on start up.

Comment: Thx. The error_log declaration was commented out in the ini (by default, presumably).  Uncommented it then restarted all WAMP services, and now the log says that php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll is "not a valid Win32 application". What does that tell us?

Comment: Yeah... wish I had better news. http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,79764

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the sqlsvr PHP PDO driver working on my slightly older version of WAMP 32-bit. Here is my setup:

- WAMP 2.2 (32 bit)

  - Apache 2.2.21
  - PHP 5.3.8
- Win 7 Pro 64 bit

Here is what I did:

1. Downloaded the MS 3.0 drivers from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098
2. Unpacked all of the files into the PHP ext folder (C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\ext)
3. Added this line to my apache php.ini file (C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.21\bin\php.ini)

   extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_53_ts.dll
4. Downloaded and installed MS SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver from here: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=239648&clcid=0x409

After these steps my PHP code happily connected to my SQL Server database.